# Phonegap / SignalR - Setting document.cookie

Tags: cordova, signalr, phonegap-build, signalr.client

I'm trying to use SignalR in a Cordova App using the Visual Studio Cordova plugin and need to be able to pass an OAuth token into SignalR.

I've implemented the solution below to pass the token via a cookie, this works fine in desktop browser - setting document.cookie = "BearerToken=" + authData.token + "; path=/";  passes the auth token into the cookie.

My problem is that when I deploy to an Android device the token is no longer passed to SignalR

http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/05/authentication-with-signalr-and-oauth.html#.VSepESjF_0c

Can anyone suggest a solution or work around?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Cordova in Visual Studio + SignalR with CORS.  If you run the index.html in the android device, the cookie is no longer supported, I use the [internal storage] instead.

In my case, I host the index.html in a web site, e.g. www.abc.com/index.html, all the users can use browsers to load the index.html, for the signalr server, I put it in www.bcd.com

However, if I run the index.html from an android device, the index.html is actually placed in the www/index.html inside the android phone file assets, which means that the [host] of this html is no longer a web server but a file, so the cookies are no longer useful.

In this case, I use a global variable in my index.html, e.g. gloMobile, to check if the index.html is running in a web server or running in a mobile phone, if I can get "http" from the http headers, I set gloMobile = true, which means that the users run it from a browser, otherwize if I do not get "http" from the http headers, the users run it inside a phone, then I use the [INTERNAL STORGE] to store [cookies].

In the SignalR server in www.bcd.com, I allow all connections from www.*.com, but for every connection, I pass the login user id and encrypted password as 2 parameters and verify them programatically myself.